# How to make new page programmatically in DNN

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

How can I make new page at the same time as the plugin is installed? Later that plugin should be at newly created page. Is it possible to do this in DNN?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot do that. The module is not executed when it is installed so you cannot create a page at that moment. You could theoretically add a page in the database during install but that is not recommended. And creating a page and adding the module to it is not the 'correct' behavior of a module.

Comment: SQL script would be the way to do this, and I would disagree with VDWWD that this isn't the "correct" behavior, there are plenty of use cases where a module could/should do that.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisHammond . So I can make SQL script in SqlDataProvider that contains information about new page and that information should be in tables PortalSettings, TabSettings, TabModules and TabPermission. Am I right? Do you maybe have an example of how I can do it right?

Comment: roughly yes, I can't recall all the specifics

Answer (score 0):

When the module is installed you can add a new page in the UpdateModule process, using something like

```
TabController.Instance.AddTab(...)
```

But I am not sure if you can also add the module itself on that page, as the install progress is propably not fully done yet. You have to try, you need a new Module instance for that and a record in TabModules with the TabID and the ModuleID.

Have a look at the IUpgradeable interface.

Happy DNNing!
Michael